# I am having install issue with Mongo DB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

im currently trying to in stall Mongo Db Compass, but i am getting the following error: Unknown option "squirrel install" and "squierrlFirstrun" (while validating preferences from: command line)
Any advice would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue when using the executable installer. The Windows 64-bit (7+) (MSI) version worked for me.